# What is a best way to append a nested structure of html elements by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to append photos to my gallery. I want to make it by jQuery. I need to append to my gallery wrapper a structure of html tags like this:

```
                <article>
                  <div class="masonry-wall-brick-wrapper">
                    <figure>
                      <a>
                        <img />
                      </a>
                      <figcaption>Photo name</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                </article>
```

Now i am using this code to append:

```
masonryWallWrapper.append('lalala');
```

but it is looks like bad idea. I have very big and unreadable string. Is there any better or best way?

Comment: Mybe have a look at http://beebole.com/pure/

Comment: possible duplicate of <link>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173589/best-way-to-create-nested-html-elements-with-jquery</link>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an HTML string, I would `clone()` a template from the DOM and re-use it:

```
<article class="template">
  <div class="masonry-wall-brick-wrapper">
    <figure>
      <a>
        <img />
      </a>
      <figcaption class="photoname">Photo name</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</article>
```

```
$(function(){
    var $article = $('article.template').clone().removeClass('template');
    $article.find('.photoname').text('something');
    masonryWallWrapper.append($article);
});
```

You might find this easier. Just my two cents.