# Create an element without closing tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

jQuery documentation doesn't mention about this case but it's still working. So, I want to mention about them a bit.

```
var div1 = $("<div></div>");
var div2 = $("<div>");
```

Both of them create same div tag, so why there is no documentation said that we should use the second for `writing code faster`?

Imagine if we want to create a template like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <span>Welcome!<span>
    </div>
</div>
```

We should do this `(1)`:

```
$('<div class="parent"><div class="child"><span>Welcome!</span></div></div>');
```

or `(2)`:

```
$('<div class="parent"></div>').html($('<div class="child"></div>').html($('<span>Welcome!</span>')));
```

or `(3)`:

```
$('<div>').addClass('parent').html($('<div>').addClass('child').html($('<span>').text('Welcome!')));

var span = $('<span>').text('Welcome!'),
    child = $('<div>').addClass('child').html(span),
    parent = $('<div>').addClass('parent').html(child);
```

As we can see, `(3)` is very easy to write and read, because we don't need to care about the closing tag.

[image: 1]

Should we have a tip to use this on the main site? If not, please correct me if there is something wrong while using it.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create nested HTML elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173589/best-way-to-create-nested-html-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is documented in section ["Creating New Elements"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

> When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img />" )` or `$( "<img>" )`, `$( "<a></a>" )` or `$( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript .createElement() function.

Comment: Thanks! I never read it before. I usually use it for all the tags. It still works fine. Maybe I don't understand why we have that quote

Comment: I mean: if we can use the short way to create all the tags, so why do we introduce that there is another way (but longer for syntax) to do. Using `$("<div>")` with `addClass`, `prop`, `attr`, `on`.... is enough for everything. No need to write: `$('<div class="mydiv" title="welcome..."></div>')`

Comment: Right but can also pass in complex html which would need to be valid. The main jQuery function is very versatile.

Comment: Here is a part in the file `dropzone.js`: https://image.ibb.co/gCtiMc/Untitled.png I belive that I never want to use it ^^!

Comment: You never know what you might need in the future....just good to know what you can do